# passing datatable page number to webservice

Tags: jquery, web-services, pagination, limit, datatables

I'm working with datatables and jQuery.

I am populating my table with the result of a web service. This web service needs to have a LIMIT clause in the associated query as there are so many results the page takes too long to load.

So my goal is to use the page numbers in my webservice call where:

If I click page 2, I will be posting up 20,40 to the limit, if I click page 3 I will be posting up 30,50.

So basically it will be the:

`page number clicked * 10` 
for the starting range and 
`page number clicked * 10 + 20` 
for the finishing range of the LIMIT clause.

However the pagenumbers displayed are based on the number of results, and if I post up my webservice with a LIMIT of 0,20 then there are only 20 results and the page numbers at the bottom of my table obviously will not have 2,3,4 etc. as options as only 20 rows were originally returned.

Is there any way around this?

Is there any better way of implementing what I want to achieve?

Some code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   tableAllocation('<?php echo $_SESSION['AuthCode']?>');

   $('#table_id').dataTable( {
    "pageLength" : "20",
    "order": [[ 0, "asc" ],[1, "asc"]]
    });

});
```

Where table allocation is a js function which calls a webservice and parses the response to populate my datatable

Comment: what webservice do you use? A PHP script? Do you have access to the database table yourself (like a mysql)?

Comment: @davidkonrad A php script yes. I do have access via my scripts

Answer (score 1):

There is a ready-made solution which is very easy to implement. It handles trivials such a `LIMIT`, ordering, paging etc out of the box. The below is for mySQL, there is made similar solutions for a [long range of databases and architectures](http://datatables.net/development/server-side/).

**1**) Goto https://legacy.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html and copy the "Server side (PHP) code" into a file, you can call it `datatables.php`

**2**) Edit the `datatables.php` credentials :

```
$gaSql['user']       = "user";  
$gaSql['password']   = "password";  
$gaSql['db']         = "database";  
$gaSql['server']     = "localhost";
```

**3**) Configure `datatables.php` table and column settings :

the table name

```
$sTable = "database table";
```

which columns to show

```
$aColumns = array( 'column1', 'column2' ... );
```

specify index column, *this is important*!

```
$sIndexColumn = "index column";
```

the index column does not have to be included in `$aColumns`.

**4**) Build the markup

```
<table id="example">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>column1</th>
        <th>column2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**5**) Create the datatable as a serverside driven datatable using `datatables.php` :

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    bProcessing: true,
    bServerSide: true,
    sAjaxSource: "datatables.php"
});
```

The above solution works with both 1.9.x and 1.10.x dataTables versions / branches.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. Will report back in a couple of hours and accept the answer once I get things working!

Comment: i'm confused from step 3 onwards...where does my web service come in (to populate my table)? The JSON received from my webservice comes from multiple database tables. Is step 5 just the js script I add into my document on load event on my webpage? Also I am using other datatable tools for saving as pdf, page numbers etc. Is this all OK with your suggested setup?

Comment: hey @user2363025  OK. This was worse, because the script assumes you are targeting one table only.  To use multiple tables, you must edit the query building, i.e `$sQuery = "...` about line 119.  If you provide table names and column names (eg the original SQL from your webservice), I might be able to make a suggestion). Dont worry about TableTools or other plugins, they work along with this approach too.  Yes, step 5 is just initialization as normal.

Comment: I pasted in my original query to the line suggested. What other additional changes will I have to make? When I pasted in my own query, i got the following alert on my webpage: dataTables warning: table id=table_id Invalid JSON response. I suspect this is because I need to make more changes to the datatables.php file. Because when my stand alone web service is called, a valid JSON is returned. Appreciate the guidance!

Comment: Hi I have fiddled around with the datatables.php file so that it now returns a proper JSON object with no errors. However on my web page, I am receiving the error 'requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0'. After googling I saw this is usually a result of the number of columns in html not matching up with the number of elements in the JSON object. This is not the case for me and I am unsure what the issue may be. Have you any experience with this?

Comment: apologies for multiple messages but I thought the additional info may help. I just got it working when I excluded my joins from the query. However, when I do include the joins, i can see I am getting a valid JSON response but am receiving the error message described above

Comment: @user2363025, there has been official holiday here until tuesday, and could not sit in front of stackoverflow constantly :) Yes, you are right - you have most certainly a mismatch between columns and the provided data, or an error in the provided data (the JSON) I am not psychic, so I have to see the markup and the JSON before I can answer anything that makes sense.  It is the same with your comment from apr 2 ...Cannot tell - how should I could advice without knowing what you have done in details?

Comment: Thanks and apologies if I have been vague. That wasn't my intention. JSON has the following format: {"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":"6295","iTotalDisplayRecords":"1163","aaData":[{"scheduleID":"11111","scheduleDate":"xxxx-xx-xx","scheduleDateEnd":"xxxx-xx-xx","scheduleTime":"xx:xx:xx","scheduleTimeEnd":"xx:xx:xx","duration":"xx:xx","userID":"2222","Status":"n\/a","carerID":"3333","QRScanned":"x","coordinatorID":"4444","hasInternet":"No","coordinatorName":"xxx ","carerCompanyID":"5555","carerCompany":"xxx","longitude":0,"latitude":0}]}. Perhaps we should move this discussion to chat?

Comment: Ran out of space in the comment above... I would like to give you all the details but would have to move to chat for that please. I think I may need to have my own callback function instead as I had so much javascript involved on that page (traffic light system) which may not work with the automatic callback function and I'm afraid I may have wasted all this time. If I did have my own callback function, would the limits still work as normal?

Comment: Thank you for your help. i ended up using a script similar to the one you provided but it could handle joins, concats etc. I have one question however..I want to wrap the entire script with an if (isset($_GET['AuthCode'])){...} whereby the user can only access the results if they have passed in a valid token. I need to know what to put in the else so I can provide an appropriate message to the user e.g. session expired, please log out and log back in and not the current message stating invalid JSON. Do you know how I would go about handling this?